# ASP.Net MVC5 Return partial view error with jQuery

Tags: jquery, partial-views, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I am trying to use ASP.NET MVC 5 to return a partial view to my page and have jQuery replace an element with what the partial view has.

Here is my controller that will handle all of these requests.

```
        public ActionResult Contact()
    {
       //Some Unrelated code
        ViewBag.Loc = "";
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Contact(form form)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Some verification code
            //Some unrelated code
            ViewBag.loc = "";
            return PartialView("_ContactThanks");
        }
        ViewBag.loc = "error";
        return View();
    }
```

Here is my form:

```
<div id="formSection>
        @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "contactForm" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            @Html.LabelFor(form => form.name)
            @Html.EditorFor(form => form.name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(form => form.name)
            @Html.LabelFor(form => form.email)
            @Html.EditorFor(form => form.email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(form => form.email)
            @Html.LabelFor(form => form.message, new { @class = "label-info" })
            @Html.EditorFor(form => form.message)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(form => form.message)
            <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" />
        }
    </div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function() {
            $('#progress').show();
            $.post().done(function(response) {
                if ("@ViewBag.loc" == "") {
                    setTimeout(function() { $('#formSection').html(response); }, 1000);
                } else {
                    $('#progress').hide();
                    $("#errorMessage").show();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

When it returns the post it will blank out the page and then reload the actual partial view instead of taking the html from the partial view and importing it into the div.

This section of code works fine when I use a standard HTML form, however I am unable to use the data validation built in with my model and controller that way.

The HTML Form that works:

```
<div id="formSection">
            <h3>@ViewBag.TheMessage</h3>
            <form method="post" id="contactForm">

                <label class="label-info">Name</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" data-bind="value: name, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" name="name" id="name" maxlength="15" spellcheck="false" required></textarea>
                <label class="label-info">Email</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="1" data-bind="value: emailadd, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" name="emailadd" id="emailadd" maxlength="30" spellcheck="false" required></textarea>                    <label class="label-info">Message</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" data-bind="value: comment, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'" name="comment" id="comment" maxlength="300" spellcheck="false" required></textarea>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" />
            </form>
        </div>
```

And the corresponding jQuery:

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function () {
        $('#progress').show();
        $.post('', {
            emailadd: $('#emailadd').val(),
            name: $('#name').val(),
            comment: $('#comment').val()
        }).done(function (response) {
            if ("@ViewBag.loc" == "") {
                setTimeout(function () { $('#formSection').html(response); }, 1000);
            } else {
                $('#progress').hide();
                $("#errorMessage").show();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You should probably use `preventDefault()` on your `submit` event handler.  Also, it's not 100% clear from the code but you don't expect `if ("@ViewBag.loc" == "") {` to be pulling that from the requested view's `ViewBag`, right?

Comment: I am having `ViewBag.Loc` return every time the page is loaded.

Comment: I suspect you're misunderstanding how server-side and client-side code works then.  The JavaScript code in your "done" handler doesn't *change itself* when it parses a response.  It gets emitted once, when the page loads, and doesn't change after that.  So it only uses the "ViewBag.loc" value from the initial page load.

Comment: When the page post's it updates that viewbag with the correct information. It works as intended on the HTML form w/jQuery with the exclusion of the server side data validation. Correct me if I am wrong but I think something else is the issue.

Comment: Look at the actual rendered client-side code.  Regardless of what you *think* it *should* do, what it *actually* does can be demonstrated and proven.  The *server-side* code updates, but it's not going to change anything in *client-side* code that is *already rendered on the page*.  AJAX requests don't work that way.  If you're going to be doing web development, you'll *really* want to understand the difference between server-side and client-side code.

Comment: I fully understand the difference between client side processing and server side processing. However, I thought that when the page posted it would re-fresh that bag. That was my mistake. But that does not explain the issue I am having because it is still not loading the page correctly. I am fairly new to this so some understanding would be great. How can I make this work? When using the HTML form it updates the page and replaces the div with the HTML from the partial view. When using the ASP.NET form it does not.

Comment: When the *whole page* posts the server-side processing will change the value.  But you're not trying to post the whole page, you're trying to make an AJAX request.  (Which should work once you use "preventDefault()" in the submit handler.)  AJAX isn't going to refresh the whole page, so the server-side processing isn't going to affect the page again.  Because the page is client-side.